# Align logo with text - Twenty Eleven child theme (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to align the text vertically with logo on the left, however it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions? Here is the css code:

```
* logo above site title */
#site-title a {
    background: url('http://www.cultsotters.org.uk/images/cults_otters_black.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 135px;
     margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
   width: auto;


}
    #branding hgroup {
    text-align: center; display: inline; margin:0; align:center;}

    #site-title, #site-description {
    margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; 
    }
```

HTMl code:

```
</head>

<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support custom-background single-author two-column right-sidebar">
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <hgroup>
                <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="http://cultsotters.org.uk/" rel="home">Cults Otters Amateur Swimming Club</a></span></h1>
                <h2 id="site-description"></h2>
            </hgroup>
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code... like maybe some HTML?

Comment: It's Wordpress, so unable to provide the HTML -but the url is http://www.cultsotters.org.uk.

Comment: Going to the page and clicking "View Source" gives your HTML.  For future reference.

Comment: Point taken. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to your CSS page in Wordpress:

```
#site-title > span > a {
    line-height: 105px;
}
```

This will pull your text down to center with the img (if it isn't exactly what you would like, adjust the `line-height`)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without all the details to visualize, but an easy trick is to set your line-height to the height of the element. assuming your logo and text have the same height here at 135px, set `line-height:35px` on your title